# Change Element style with window height with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to change the background colour of a div element when the page window height is lower than a certain value using JavaScript. I have a vague idea of how this might work but it doesn't seem to be having any effect.
This is within a  tag and loads after the body of my HTML.

```
<script>
var footer = document.getElementByClassName("footer");

if (window.innerHeight < 800) {
footer.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}
</script>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements, so the `footer.style.backgroundColor` assignment will fail, as you would have seen had you looked at the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like already mentioned `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. You had a typo there so nothing was returned, however.

As long as there's only 1 element with the class name "footer" this should work (might be better to use an ID):

```
<script>
var footer = document.getElementsByClassName("footer")[0];

if (window.innerHeight < 800) {
    footer.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
}
</script>
```

But yeah, you should really look at the dev console when you're writing Javascript. It can save a lot of headaches!

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not have a method called `getElementByClassName`.

The closest thing is `getElementsByClassName` which returns an `HTMLCollection` which is an array-like object, so to get the first element in the list you have use an index:

`var footer = document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0];`

You can also use `querySelector` to get the first element with the class name:

`var footer = document.querySelector('.footer');`

Here is a working example:

```js
var footer = document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0];

window.onresize = function (event) {
    if (window.innerHeight < 800) {
        footer.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    } else {
        footer.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
}
```

```css
.footer {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer"></footer>
```

**JSFiddle Demo http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/x63rc6v4/1/**